# How to create a function return nothing in Julia?

Tags: function, julia

When I create a function in Julia, I print something in the function and don't return anything. But the result is the function print what I want and also return 'nothing'. What can I do to make the function just print what I want without return 'nothing'?

Answer (score 9):

There is always a return value from a function. When there is no explicit `return` statement, the value of the last expression in the function is returned. This is probably what you're seeing here: if the `print` statement is the last line of your function, since `print`'s return value is `nothing`, that becomes the return value of your function too.

If you just don't want the `nothing` shown at the end of the output,then please paste the code you're using that leads to this behaviour, and we can figure out how to suppress this output of `nothing` from appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Some additional comment to the answer by @sundar.

In other words `nothing` is the value meaning that the function did not return anything. Consider this Julia session:

```
julia> function f()
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> res = f()

julia> dump(res)
Nothing nothing
```

By default `nothing` is displayed as an empty output:

```
julia> res
```

This however changes when `res` ends up interpolated in another string:

```
julia> "$res"  
"nothing"
```

For cases like above consider using `something` such as:

```
julia> "$(something(res,""))"
""
```